# Mockito test does not trigger unique constraint violation in H2

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, h2, spring-boot-test, mockito-kotlin

I'm trying to write tests to make sure that my service layer is working as expected. However, when I try to violate a unique constraint and expect to see a DataIntegrityViolationException, it seems that this is ignored instead.

Here's my schema at the moment:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_users(
    uuid UUID PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
    username VARCHAR UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    is_deleted BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
);
```

As you can see, my username is unique.

```
@Entity(name = "table_users")
data class User(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    val uuid: UUID? = null,

    @Column(name = "username", unique = true)
    @NotNull(message = "Please provide a username") @NotBlank
    val username: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "password")
    @NotNull @NotBlank
    var password: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotNull(message = "Please provide a first name.") @NotBlank
    var firstName: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @NotNull @NotBlank
    var lastName: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    @NotNull
    var isDeleted: Boolean = false
) {
    // Omitted builder class for brevity
}
```

Here's my saveUser method so far:

```
override fun saveUser(user: User): DatabaseResult<User> {
        return try {
            if(user.firstName.isNullOrBlank()) {
                return DatabaseResult(
                    code = ResultCode.CREATION_FAILURE,
                    errorMessage = UserService.ErrorMessages.FIRST_NAME_NULL_OR_BLANK
                )
            }

            if(user.lastName.isNullOrBlank()) {
                return DatabaseResult(
                    code = ResultCode.CREATION_FAILURE,
                    errorMessage = UserService.ErrorMessages.LAST_NAME_NULL_OR_BLANK
                )
            }

            if(user.username.isNullOrBlank()) {
                return DatabaseResult(
                    code = ResultCode.CREATION_FAILURE,
                    errorMessage = UserService.ErrorMessages.USERNAME_NULL_OR_BLANK
                )
            }

            val savedUser = userRepository.save(user)

            DatabaseResult(
                code = ResultCode.CREATION_SUCCESS,
                entity = savedUser
            )
        } catch(exception: DataAccessException) {
            DatabaseResult(
                code = ResultCode.CREATION_FAILURE,
                errorMessage = exception.message.toString()
            )
        } catch(exception: DataIntegrityViolationException) {
            DatabaseResult(
                code = ResultCode.CREATION_FAILURE,
                errorMessage = exception.message.toString()
            )
        } catch(exception: ConcurrencyFailureException) {
            DatabaseResult(
                code = ResultCode.CREATION_FAILURE,
                errorMessage = exception.message.toString()
            )
        } catch(exception: OptimisticLockingFailureException) {
            DatabaseResult(
                code = ResultCode.CREATION_FAILURE,
                errorMessage = exception.message.toString()
            )
        } catch(exception: Exception) {
            DatabaseResult(
                code = ResultCode.CREATION_FAILURE,
                errorMessage = exception.message.toString()
            )
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I'm expecting a few different exceptions to be raised by the database and my repository code.

```
    @Test
    fun givenExistingUsername_whenSaved_thenReturnFailureResult() {
        // Given
        val existingUser = User.Builder()
            .firstName("John")
            .lastName("Doe")
            .username("existing_username")
            .password("password")
            .isDeleted(false)
            .build()

        userService.saveUser(existingUser)

        val userWithExistingUsername = User.Builder()
            .firstName("Jane")
            .lastName("Doe")
            .username("existing_username")  // Use the same existing username
            .password("password")
            .isDeleted(false)
            .build()

        // When
        val savedTest = userService.saveUser(userWithExistingUsername)

        // Then
        Mockito.verify(repository, Mockito.never()).save(userWithExistingUsername)  // Verify that the save method is never called again
        assertEquals(ResultCode.CREATION_FAILURE, savedTest.code)
        assertNull(savedTest.entity)
        assertNotNull(savedTest.errorMessage)
        // Adjust the error message verification according to your implementation
        assertEquals(UserService.ErrorMessages.USERNAME_NOT_UNIQUE, 
savedTest.errorMessage)
    }
```

As previously mentioned, when I try to run the above test code, regardless of what I do, it still seems to return a second object for the second user despite it having an identical username between the both of them.

It's as if the unique constraint is entirely ignored.

Also, please explain like I'm 5 as I'm quite new to testing code.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you didn't provide the code of your tests (?).

Comment: Updated OP with the test code. Sorry about that

Comment: Is there a field that you could give a different value to for each save? Then you could tell if both saves are actually executed (and maybe see if the database has two records anyway).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Although a couple are the same, the main one is username which is unique.

Comment: Or do you mean adding another unique field?

Comment: @JamieRhys You expect an exception when adding the second record, but aren't getting it. Either one (first or second) record is not being added (so no exception), or it's being added with no exception. Looking at the table will tell you if there are two, or if there is one then changing a field between records should tell you if the second record replaced the first, or was not added at all.

Comment: @JamieRhys Just to add, the problem might be your test, or your constraints, or something else. This is to suggest where to start looking.